# Creating Layer editing/Analysis in ArcGIS web map application using Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, postgresql, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, esri-geodatabase

I want to make an ArcGIS web map application in which user can select different layers of the published map (data of the layer in Postrgresql) and do some analysis based on layer data.import data to the application. Some kind of Interactive map.

1) Do I need Geodatabase or just registered postgresql database with Arcgis for Server and ArcGIs for Desktop 10.1 is enough?

2) any sample template for javascript API is available?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the analysis? Are you talking about geoprocessing, or simple queries, or? Or are you talking about the new Online-Analytics?

Comment: by analyzing the map I mean user can select what features of layers of the map he wants, see the data of the layers, the ability to  import new data as another layer to the map.

Comment: It would depend on the type of analysis. You would either need a library or postgis or the esri tools. That is the benefit of using esri they have many tools that do the work.  Please edit the original question with more information. Are you trying to do it all with esri tools or are you exploring ways to accomplish it with other tools? Actually just noticed the arcgis JavaScript tag that would imply you need all esri tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcCatalog will turn your database into a geodatabase.

ArcGIS Javascript API has the esri/layers/FeatureLayer for filtering features.

If by analysis you mean analytical tools on the resulting feature data then there are no pivot charts/grids out-of-the box.  If you mean filtering features based on domain values then it's very easy to do yourself.  Have a look at the "fields" property on the FeatureLayer.

For samples you might want to start with the FeatureLayer and Query samples:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#search/FeatureLayer
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#search/Query

One feature that comes to mind is "count":

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#querycount

Also, be aware that you can "require" a FeatureServer service:

```
require(["http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer?f=json&callback=define"], 
function (serviceDescription) {...});
```

To facilitate importing/discovering layers.